# How to read the value of elment from one xml in to another another xml?

Tags: java, xml

i have below  element in one of the xml file say xmlA

```
<dataSourceProperties>
    <url>jdbc:JSQLConnect://US-L-17:1433/database=MyDatastore</url>
    <userName>Database1</userName>
    <password>US@123</password>
</dataSourceProperties>
```

In another XML say XMLB i want to read the value of element URL from XMLA  in to below property value(as both are having same value)

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:JSQLConnect://US-L-17:1433/database=MyDatastore</property>
```

both xml files are different drives and different folder structure.

Comment: maybe this can help http://www.javablogging.com/read-and-write-xml/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse xmlA, retrieve url information and save in a variable. Afterwards you need to parse xmlB, find the suitable location in the model (model of xmlB after you parse it) and create the property with the value you already saved in the variable.